# Why do I have different encoders generating the same results?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression, pipeline

I was working with [California Housing Prices dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/camnugent/california-housing-prices), and this is what I've done:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

housing = pd.read_csv("housing.csv")

X = housing.drop(["longitude", "latitude", "median_house_value"], axis=1)
y = housing["median_house_value"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42
)

import category_encoders as ce

encoder_list = [ce.WOEEncoder(), ce.OneHotEncoder()]

for encoder in encoder_list:

    numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
        steps=[
            ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
            ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
        ]
    )

    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
        steps=[
            ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="constant")),
            ("encoder", encoder),
        ]
    )

    pipe = Pipeline(
        steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor), ("regressor", LinearRegression())]
    )

    pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

    pipe.predict(X_test)

    print(encoder)
    print(pipe.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Why is this generating two similar results? Shouldn't they be different? The same is happening when I try different scalers.

Comment: Where is the `preprocessor` defined?!